# What is the convention for deciding which resource to place an endpoint under?

Tags: design, web-development, api, api-design

I have an endpoint that teachers can use to invite students to a virtual classroom by providing their emails in a list format. Let's call it `POST invite-students`. I have these four resources:

1. `api/v1/virtual-school` - includes endpoints for inviting teachers and editing their permissions
2. `api/v1/virtual-classroom` - includes endpoints for creating and fetching classroom objects
3. `api/v1/student` - includes endpoints for fetching student objects
4. `api/v1/teacher` - includes endpoints for fetching teacher objects

I'm not sure where to place the new endpoint to invite students. Does it make more sense to place it under `student` because it's about students or to place it under `teacher` because that's an action only teachers can take? Alternatively, I could place it under `virtual-classroom` since the students are getting invited to the classroom.

I understand this is subjective and I apologize in advance if this SE isn't meant for questions like this. I'm interested in conventions/rules people have used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we call an "invite" is really the *creation* of an entry in the cross table between a student, a teacher and a classroom.

Sometimes, that cross table is a technical consideration that is not explicitly part of the domain. Other times, that cross table is considered an individual resource in and of itself.
For example, if this were a video rental store application, the cross table between customers and videos would be its own resource, i.e. the "rental".

In your case, I would call that cross entity a "lesson" (for lack of a better term). It seems to me that your lessons will be a managed resource with their own features and lifecycle, so it makes sense to register these as their own resource, e.g. a `/lesson` endpoint.

That being said, how you structure your API is up to you. While `POST /lesson` might sound the most straightforward, there's nothing stopping you from using something like `POST /student/invite` if that URL looks more thematically appropriate to you.

If this was pure REST, then `/lesson` would be the way to go, but you did not tag the question as such.

Comment: Thank you for the info, `/lesson` makes sense 